# How can one prove $||z_1|-|z_2||\le|z_1+z_2|$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

How can it be shown that for the complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$:
$$||z_1|-|z_2||\le|z_1+z_2|$$
My text provides a hint that $z_1=z_1+z_2+(-z_2)$, and $z_2=z_1+(-z_1)+z_2$.
$${}$$

Comment: Apply the triangular inequality to one of the given equalities in the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the triangle inequality:
$$|z_1+z_2|\le |z_1|+|z_2|$$
so using it we have
$$|z_1|=|(z_1+z_2)-z_2|\le|z_1+z_2|+|z_2|$$
hence we find
$$|z_1|-|z_2|\le |z_1+z_2|\tag1$$
and interchange the role of $z_1$ and $z_2$ we find
$$|z_2|-|z_1|\le |z_1+z_2|\tag2$$
and finally $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Excellent! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

$$|z_1|=|z_1-z_2 +z_2|\leq |z_1-z_2| +|z_2|$$
so 
$$|z_1|-|z_2|\leq |z_1-z_2| $$
now by symmetry 
$$|z_2|-|z_1|\leq |z_1-z_2| $$

This gives
$$||z_2|-|z_1||\leq |z_1-z_2| $$ as this holds for all $z_1$ and $z_2$ we can change the sign of $z_2$ to get also
$$||z_2|-|z_1||\leq |z_1+z_2| $$

Comment: typo: the OP aims at $z_1+z_2$. Not $z_1-z_2$

Comment: I suggest to leave it as it is. This inequality is also true, and a correction would result in three identical answers ...

Answer (score 1):

In general $\left|a+b\right|\leq\left|a\right|+\left|b\right|$.

Applying
that on $z_{1}=z_{1}+z_{2}+\left(-z_{2}\right)$ gives:

$$\left|z_{1}\right|=\left|z_{1}+z_{2}+\left(-z_{2}\right)\right|\leq\left|z_{1}+z_{2}\right|+\left|-z_{2}\right|=\left|z_{1}+z_{2}\right|+\left|z_{2}\right|$$

so that $$\left|z_{1}\right|-\left|z_{2}\right|\leq\left|z_{1}+z_{2}\right|$$

Switching $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ gives: $$\left|z_{2}\right|-\left|z_{1}\right|\leq\left|z_{1}+z_{2}\right|$$

This together allows the conclusion that $$\left|\left|z_{1}\right|-\left|z_{2}\right|\right|\leq\left|z_{1}+z_{2}\right|$$